# Automatically Setting Printer ACLs for Multiple Printers on Multiple Terminal Servers

Tags: windows-terminal-services, batch, printer, security-groups

Does anyone have an example of how to script (preferably as a batch file) to set ACLs on multiple printers installed on multiple servers? I searched Google and found some examples of settings ACLs on a single printer but not for multiple printers on multiple servers.

If no one has any available solutions I will write something from scratch but if I don't have to reinvent the wheel great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the GPO is processed on the Terminal Services Servers which creates the printers, we just need to use subinacl to remove the everyone group from the restricted printers' permissions and then add the domain security group that will be allowed to print to the restricted printers.

```
subinacl /printer *printername* /revoke="EVERYONE"
subinacl /printer *printername* /grant="*domain*\*domain security group*"=P
```